# Nancyfx self-hosting cannot stop HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nancy, httplistener

I have an app, which has a rest-service based on NancyFx and i find it very cool framework. But i have a very big problem with stopping it.
My host class looks like this:

```
public class RestHost : IStartStopAble
{
    private readonly string _uri;
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    private NancyHost _host;
    private Thread _wsThread;
    private WindsorBootstrapper _windsorBootstrapper;

    public RestHost(string uri, IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _uri = uri;
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(_uri);

        _windsorBootstrapper = new WindsorBootstrapper(_container);
        _host = new NancyHost(uri, _windsorBootstrapper);

        _host.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

AS you can see, i use windsor along with Nancy. Everything works great, i call Start, Stop and constructor from main thread, but when i Dispose my host i catch this:

```
 HttpListener: HttpListenerException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

exception. I found this paper: http://maykov.blogspot.ru/2009/02/c-httplistener-httplistenerexception-io.html but i use main thread and don't understand how can i "Save" the thread, in which HttpListener is created and, also, how can i pass it to Nancy.

I'll be very gratefull for any help, still i don't even know, what can i do with HttpListener exception in core of .Net framework.

Comment: Should just use the OWIN self host instead.

Comment: @Phill i use Linux servers, is OWIN working there?

Comment: Unless something has changed, it works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may remember the `SynchronizationContext`:

```
public void Start()
{
    // init _host ...

    _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    _host.Start();
}

public void Stop()
{
    if (_syncContext == SynchronizationContext.Current)
    {
        _host.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        _syncContext.Post((state) =>
        {
            _host.Dispose();
        }
        , null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This works. Anyway, i now host my service as daemon and linux manages my process correctly.

Comment: Just in case anyone has a similar trouble: in my app, Nancy was running inside a WPF app and was expected to terminate on window close, but instead the app hanged. This solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for me, because of the currently running **Quartz Scheduler**. There is no virtual method at NancyBootstrapper for shutdown process. So here is my solution:

In *NancyBootStrapper.ApplicationStartup* I'm setting scheduler to static class (which is i'm not happy with that) field called **GlobalModule.TaskScheduler**:

```
GlobalModule.TaskScheduler = ScheduleTasksAndStartScheduler(container);
GlobalModule.Logger = _logger;
```

Here is the GlobalModule:

```
public static class GlobalModule
{
    public static ILogger Logger;
    public static ITaskScheduler TaskScheduler;

    public static void StopScheduler()
    {
        if (TaskScheduler == null) return;
        try
        {
            TaskScheduler.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Logger != null)
            {
                Logger.Error("TaskScheduler.Stop()", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And at last Program.Stop:

```
private static void Stop(NancyHost host)
    {
        GlobalModule.StopScheduler();
        if (_syncContext == SynchronizationContext.Current)
        {
            host.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            _syncContext.Post((state) =>
            {
                host.Dispose();
            }
            , null);
        }
        try
        {
            host.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception: {0}\r\n Stack Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        }
    }
```

Kind regards...